# Lazy load tabs next to selected tab

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to lazy load/preload the one or two tabs next to the selected one to avoid a laggy animation on tab changing. Is there a way to do that with flutter ? I am actually using a defaultTabController

```
home: DefaultTabController(
    initialIndex: 0,
    length: 5,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(

          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'HARDWARE'),
            Tab(text: 'SCHEDULE'),
            Tab(text: 'ANALYTICS'),
            Tab(text: 'TEMP'),
            Tab(text: 'SETTINGS'),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('${widget.title}'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          TheGridView().build(),
          TimePicker(),
          ChartPage(),
          TempPage(),
```

Comment: Hi @qeude, any findings on this?

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, I'm not working on this anymore sorry

Answer (score 0):

There's not much details on what you're trying to load on your tabs. If the tab page stutters during tab change, the elements being rendered on the page might be blocked in the main thread. If you're using [Future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) callbacks before `Widget build()`, you may want to consider modifying where it's called.